# Changing cygwin home path

Tags: windows, powershell, cygwin

How do I set the cygwin home path to just C drive. 
At present, in the cygwin\etc\nsswitch.conf file, the db_home is set to /home/%u 
It goes to c:\users\username </br/>

Comment: `db_home:  /home/%U` should point to `/home/username`  . Have you a `/home` directory ? What is the output of `SET | grep HOME` ?

Comment: Home directory is set to C:/users/username

Comment: Again: what is the output of the command  `set | grep HOME`  ?